# How to access EJB3 deployed on Jboss AS 7/ EAP 6 with Corba/IIOP client?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly-8, jboss-eap-6

I am looking for some hint or possibly an example on exposing EJB3 as IIOP/CORBA compliant while deploying on Jboss AS 7/ EAP 6 and accessing the same EJB3 with IIOP/CORBA client.

Our current application is designed as such that it’s EJBs(EJB3) are exposed to CORBA/IIOP clients and all our WEB and standalone clients are using those EJBs using IIOP/CORBA protocol.

Example:

```
Properties props= new Properties(); 
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","192.00.00.00"); 
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort","3700"); 
initialContext= new InitialContext(props);
```

As Glassfish fully supports corba protocol and it works fine. Now, I want the same working with Jboss AS 7/ EAP 6 or in new version wildfly.

Any inputs or help on the same will leads to us in deciding to select Jboss AS7/EAP 6 as the suitable candidate for our applications server in place of Glassfish.

Thanks